# [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path

Tags: java, ms-access-2007, jdbc-odbc

I have created DSN for Mapped drive like this:-

```
 Y:\\192.168.2.5\data\db.accdb
```

Now i am accessing this database from java application using sun jdbc odbc drivers. Application is running on Window 2008 64-bit system and database is running on Window Server 2012 64-bit system.

When I ran this application with Java 64-bit it throw error of architecture mismatch.

Then i install java of 32-bit and the above problem is resolved. But getting another problem as

```
  java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is
  not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that yo
  u are connected to the server on which the file resides.
```

How to resolve this problem?

[image]

See the database path witch is not valid for my program. This path is mapped with **Y:\192.168.2.5\shared** drive.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered, it seems, that a mapped network drive is not available to IIS as it runs as a service.  In addition, I have been unable to create a DSN entry with a UNC path.  So, I created the DSN with a local database, then changed the path in Regedit.  What a pain.  Be sure to provide proper credentials (UID and PWD).

Answer (score 0):

Use a valid PATH, the problem with this

```
Y:\\192.168.2.5\data\db.accdb
```

Is that `\` is a special character. You need,

```
Y:\\192.168.2.5\\data\\db.accdb
```

or

```
Y:/192.168.2.5/data/db.accdb
```

Comment: How to replace special character \ by \\. I am creating System DSN under 'ODBC Data Source Administrator' window.

Comment: You aren't going to get a Java exception from the Microsoft control panel. Please clarify your question, and specify your java version.

Comment: I have created a simple java program for accessing *.accdb database. When this database is on same machine there is no error. But when the database in remote system it throw **'[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path'** exception. For accessing remote database I have created a mapped drive for *.accdb file. Then I created dsn for this mapped file. Please see the image I have attached with this question.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize I bet this was a permission problem.

Was having the exact same error message and was baffled because it was working earlier.  It was because I was changing versions of Tomcat on my end and it was running without permission to access my db resource.

Answer (score 0):

so I had a similar, if not the same, issue.

had installed wamp. 
was using php to access a mdb file on the network. and I got the msg saying path not found.

so what I did was, created a normal dsn configuration and then how it looked like was something like this:
Y:\mydata.mdb

I searched for "y:\mydata.mdb" on regedit and found it.
changed it to full path for example like "\serverip\serverfolder\mydata.mdb"

This was done on administrative user.

I refreshed the web page and it worked.
Hope this helps somebody.

p.s.
written on a rush. sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this connection string by spelling out the fully qualified dns name, instead of using the mapped drive name `"H:":`

BAD

```
sCN_ODBC = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=H:\vol01\IIT\Apps\Applications\MFG\User.mdb;Trusted_Connection=yes";
```

GOOD

```
sCN_ODBC = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=\\tstorage.iit.edu\depts$\vol01\IIT\Apps\Applications\MFG\User.mdb;Trusted_Connection=yes";
```

I'm using C# dotnet , other posts on this thread are java and php